# Replace a character with "<?" in str_replace on php

Tags: php, html, special-characters, str-replace

I wanna replace a character with `<?` string in php.

```
$tp ="UtmpV"; 
$tp = str_replace("U", "<?", $tp);
$tp = str_replace("V", " ; ?>", $tp);
echo $tp;
```

But it shown as a comment in html:
`<!--? echo tmp; ?-->`

How can I do this?

Comment: You only need to show `<?php echo $tmp; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but try:

```
$tp ="UtmpV"; 
$tp = str_replace("U", "&lt;? ", $tp);
$tp = str_replace("V", " ?&gt;", $tp);
echo $tp;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But I edit Question!